# Do I need to disable iCloud Storage Plan to change iTunes store?

Tags: itunes, icloud

In order to change an iTunes store (switch to another country) I need to cancel my **Apple Music** subscription. I knew that, but what I didn't know is that after cancelling it I have to wait till the paid period ends, even though I don't care and would like to change the store right now.

But okay, that's water under the bridge, and soon this period will end. However, I have a paid **iCloud Storage Plan** as well. Should it be reset to default 5 GB as well in order to switch between iTunes stores?

I mean, if after my current **Apple Music** paid period will finally vanish, is it possible that iTunes will ask me to cancel **iCloud Storage Plan** too, and then I'll have to wait till the end of its paid period as well? So I better to reset it to default 5 GB right now?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I contacted **Apple Support**, and they told me this:

> If you have an iCloud Storage subscription, you need to downgrade your
>   active storage subscription to its original before you change your
>   country or region.

So I did.

However, I am not sure if it was really necessary (because there was no red label about this in country settings like it was with Apple Music), but I didn't want to sacrifice one more month of waiting for that experiment. This is why I don't mark this answer as an accepted solution for the original question.